# Sometimes can't move QT based apps windows by dragging title bars

Tags: 20.04, qt

I'm on 20.04 LTS, using vanilla gnome shell and using Xorg.

I've noticed that sometimes certain apps' titlebars become unresponsive to clicks/drags. The window's there and the app works just fine, but Gnome seems to not be aware of it!

I believe this problem is specific to QT based apps (e.g. VirtualBox).

Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround?